# Insert variable within a string in two locations

Tags: python, string-formatting

How would I get the year string in two locations in my filepath

```
year = str(date.today().year)
filename = r'output.csv\Year\{}.csv'.format(year)
```

It works with one bracket to change the `{}` to `2016.csv` but

If I replace `Year` with a second `{}` to `r'output.csv\{}\{}.csv'.format(year)` it says `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [1]: 'output.csv/{0}/{0}.csv'.format(2016)
Out[1]: 'output.csv/2016/2016.csv'
```

With empty curly brackets, `format` just implies that each of the consecutive occurrences of `{}` corresponds to one of the positional arguments that you pass.
If you want a different order, just specify an index explicitly.

[String Formatting Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Also note that I am using slashes as separators, which is considered better practice with file paths, and that I used an `int` as year (so your conversion to `str` is unnecessary).

Comment: @ Lev Levitsky I need it to change with the current year and keep `.format(year)` so it changes to 2017 when the time comes. I wasn't that clear sorry

Comment: @iOSecure just use your `year` variable. I am using 2016 for demonstration, because your question is in fact about string formatting and not how to get the current year.

Comment: @ Lev Levitsky oh ok thank you, so if I had a `\Month\Year` and needed to pull from two different strings it would be `\{0}\{1}.csv.format(year)(month)` ?

Comment: @iOSecure In that case you can use indices, too - `'\{1}\{0}.csv'.format(year, month)` - note how we pass year and then month but the indexes in the format string are 1 and then 0 - or you could just pass them in the correct order and not use any indexes: `'\{}\{}.csv'.format(month, year)`. I've added a link to documentation for reference.